# Problemas con mi Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio, build.gradle

Android Studio pero no funciona bien y no se como solucionarlo

[image: estos serian los erroresm, yo solo quise crear la app]

[image]

Comment: Hola Beatriz, bienvenida a [es.so]. ¿Puedes **sustituir** las imagenes por el codigo y los errores en formato de **texto** ?  Asi será mas facil de visualizar en cualquier dispositivo (y una carga mas rapida) además de poder copiar y pegar. Mira [ask] para aprender a mejorar la calidad de tus preguntas. Has de añadir una explicacion de lo que quieres hacer y lo que has intentado junto a por que no te funciona. Un saludo

Comment: Para poder ayudarte tienes que mostrarnos el contenido que tienes en el archivo `build.gradlle(Project App)`

Answer (score 0):

Yo lo primero que haría es actualizar la plataforma y plugins. El error que te da es porque no ha podido sincronizar el proyecto.

Un saludo,

Answer (score 0):

En el menú Build > Clean y luego Build > Rebuild luego en la pestaña de aviso sincronizar el gradle con "Try again". Si a este punto todo no está normal entonces verifica las librerías en la parte superior de la(s) clase(s). Es posible que necesites importar algunas librerías, agregarlas al Gradle:Module o descargarlas desde File > Settings > SDK Manager.

Varias cosas sencillas pueden causar ese comportamiento de Android Studio, sobretodo el tema de librerías faltantes que necesitan agregarse y/o sincronizarse con tu proyecto.

Answer (score 0):

El problema es que no puede resolver algunas dependencias que estan definidas dentro de tu archivo `/app/build.gradle`, a simple vista puedes ver clases del paquete `javax.*`, las cuales no son soportadas por [Android SDK](https://developer.android.com/reference/classes.html).

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Incluso librerias como Javawriter no es soportada en una aplicación Android:

https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.squareup/javawriter/2.2.1